# Etymology of "nada" and "nadie"

Tags: etimología, pronombres, latín

In English, the words to describe the total absence of anything or anybody (and other similar meanings) are *nothing* and *nobody*, whose etymologies are quite direct: "no thing" or "not any thing" and the some for "no body" or "not one body".

In Spanish we have *nada* and *nadie*. According to RAE's dictionary:

- *[Nada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QCFVQse)* comes from Latin *[res] nata*: "born [thing]".
- *[Nadie](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QCTdnse)* comes from *[nadi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QCTBvh1)* which comes from Latin *nati*: "the born ones".

So what I would like to know is: how did words that meant the existence of someone ("the born ones", "born things") come to mean the total absence of anything or anybody?

Comment: Está muy bien explicado aquí: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?nada. `Nada` viene de una expresión: `res nata` Por cierto: si en castellano utilizamos `nata`, en catalán utilizamos `res` y en frances `rien`

Comment: Eso suena a posible respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This phenomenon is known as the [Jespersen's Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle), and the Spanish case is described here:

> *Nada* 'nothing' and *nadie* 'nobody' illustrate a completely different linguistic process, one common enough to have its own name: Jespersen's cycle, in honor of Otto Jespersen, the Danish linguist who first wrote about it in 1917. The cycle takes place when a positive element reinforces, and eventually replaces, an existing negative. It's as if the English expression *a bit*, which reinforces the word *not* in sentences like *I'm not a bit hungry*, were to become negative itself. In the case of *nadie* and *nada*, the cycle began with the Latin expressions *non homines nati* 'no people born' and *non res nata* 'nothing born,' which were roughly equivalent to English 'not a soul' and 'nothing on Earth.' As Latin evolved into Spanish, instead of these phrases becoming compounds, the adjectives *nati* and *nata* became stand-alone negatives, in the process undergoing the slight phonetic changes that produced *nadie* and *nada*.<sup>7</sup>
>
> - [*¿Por qué? 101 Questions About Spanish*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z9kaDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT165&lpg=PT165&dq=jespersen%27s+cycle+%22spanish%22+nadie), Judy Hochberg
>   <sub>Question 40. Why do most Spanish negatives begin with *n*?</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the shift in meaning is analogous to the one that made [the French word *personne* come to mean "nobody"](https://www.quora.com/How-did-personne-come-to-mean-nobody-in-French). Suppose you have a word that means "nothing" but that word is weakened by constant use, or eroded by phonetic change to the point that it's too short or too weak or somehow not enough to indicate "nothing".

As explained in [this other website](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?nada), there was already in Latin an idiom (*res nata*) that expressed the idea of "the thing or matter under consideration". Two things then took place: 1) other forms of expressing the idea of "nothing" fell out of favor, as indicated above; 2) the existing idiom was associated with negation so much that in time it became a negative itself without the need of an auxiliary negative particle (like French *personne*).